# Window not defined - Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm getting the error that 'window is not defined'. Kindly assist

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            // detect scroll

            setActive(window.scrollY > 100);
        };

        // add event listener

        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        // clear event listener

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
}}, []);
```

[image: Code Snippet]

Comment: if you are in `useEffect`, that means on client side and `window` is always defined. you dont need `if` guard to check if it is defined. i think somewhere you are using client library on the server side. client library wants to access to `window` but since you are on the server `window` is undefined.

Comment: next time, pls do not share screenshot. not everyone's device can load images sometimes, not everyone is on the desktop checking your post with hight speed internet

Comment: is ssr enabled?

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, the code snippet has nothing to do with the error. It is telling you that somewhere you're importing `leaflet` which apparently accesses the `window` object.

You should most likely dynamically import that module with [`next/dynamic` with no SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because the leaflet library was using SSR instead of client, resulting in the error 'window is not defined'. I solved this by importing dynamic from nextjs. Please see the below screenshot

https://prnt.sc/RWuE55T6skuA